# Node-Red: how can I send a message from a Javascript function inside an HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I am trying to send a message after the update of a round slider in an template node written in HTML. This is the code:

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
    radius: 100,
    width: 14,
    value: 20,
    handleSize: 35,
    startAngle: "315",
    endAngle: "+270",
    //start: "traceEvent",
    //stop: "traceEvent",
    create: "traceEvent",
    drag: "traceEvent"
    });

    function traceEvent(e) {
        var vol = (e.value);
        document.getElementById('volume').value = vol;
        return vol;
    }
    </script>
<style>
    #slider {
     border-radius: 1000px;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(123, 123, 123);
    }
    .rs-border {
     border-width: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Basically I was expecting that a message should be triggered by the command `return vol` in the function `traceEvent`, but this is not working.

Any ideas please?

Comment: is your problem solved now?

Comment: Unfortunately not... I kind of gave up for the moment and decided to use a normal angular slider.

Comment: If possible you can let me know your application details and scenario, I will try to provide you the solution. You can let me know here: http://roundsliderui.com/contactme.html

Answer (score 1):

If you read about half-way down the `ui_template` node's info (in the sidebar), you'll find this example:

> Sending a message:

```
<script>
    var value = "hello world";
    // or overwrite value in your callback function ...
    this.scope.action = function() { return value; }
</script>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">
    Click me to send a hello world
</md-button>
```

> Will display a button that when clicked will send a message with the payload 'Hello world'.

In my experience, it can be even simpler than that -- depending upon what data you are trying to send back to your node-red flow. The angular `scope` already contains a `send(msg)` function, so you can trigger that directly from any angular event (in this example, on the ng-click event of the button) -- using the plain html `onclick` event would not have the same access to the angular scope.

In your example, the inclusion of the `<html>` element is not necessary, since you are only building a portion of the existing dashboard page. If you define your `traceEvent(e)` function inside the angular scope, it should be available to be called from the slider library (something like this, untested):

```
<script>
(function($scope) {
    function traceEvent(e) {
        var vol = (e.value);
        var msg = { "volume": vol };
        $scope.send(msg);
    }
})(scope);
</script>
```

Assuming that the slider "drag" event will call `traceEvent` with an `event` object containing a `value` property, you should get a msg sent through the output port of your ui_template node, every time the slider changes position.

*Incidentally, you should also move your external library links to a separate `ui_template` node, with its Template Type set to "Added to site `<head>` section" -- this helps to ensure that your external libs are loaded **before** you try to render them on the dashboard page.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great hints @SteveR ! Do you mean somethink like this? It is actually not working... `<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#slider").roundSlider({
        radius: 100,
        drag: "traceEvent"
    });
        (function($scope) {
            function traceEvent(e) {
                var vol = (e.value);
                var msg = { "volume": vol };
                document.getElementById("volume").value = vol;
                $scope.send(msg);
            }
        })(scope);
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the `template` node (core node) and not the `template-ui` node (part of the Dashboard-ui set of nodes) you can not natively trigger flows with a javascript function.

The `traceEvent()` function runs entirely within the page you've created in the template node on the remote browser, it knows nothing about Node-RED, it just happened to have been loaded from there.

If you want to trigger an action the simplest way to do it is to have another http-in/http-response node pair and to make a ajax style http request from within your `traceEvent()` function.

If on the other hand you are using the `template-ui` node as part of the node-red-dashboard then you need to look at using angular to build a component, not a full html page.

Comment: Thanks for the great hints ! I am actually using the `template-ui`, but I decided to this approach because of the round Slider, better in terms of design than the usual slider from angular. Is there any way I can send a message to another node out of it?